# Could not find 'sprockets' (~> 2.2.1) among 166 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sprockets

Gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets',        git: 'https://github.com/tessi/sprockets.git', branch: '2_2_2_backport2'
gem 'sprockets-rails',  git: 'https://github.com/finnlabs/sprockets-rails.git', branch: 'backport'
```

when we are stating server, we are facing issue

Error:

```
/home/kannan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'sprockets' (~> 2.2.1) among 166 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/kannan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /home/kannan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `each'
```

The result is we are unable to start the application.

Ref project
https://github.com/opf/openproject

Comment: delete `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again

Comment: We tried that also @AndreyDeineko

Comment: How are you starting the server? Try running `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: I saw `/.idea` in your `.gitignore`, so i guess you're using RubyMine. If I'm right, then check your RubyMine's settings at `Languages & Frameworks > Ruby SDK and Gems`, and compare it to the output of `rvm list`.

Comment: No,  rails s  @makhan